# Python to exe automatically close

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, py2exe

I wrote a .py code and converted it to a .exe using pyinstaller.
It report the following problem:

1. If I double click the .exe the program execute correctly (takes some input file, takes some input user digit, saves some output files etc..). When it ends the window automatically closes and I do not have time to look at the stamps.
2. If I execute the .exe calling it from command prompt I do not register this problem. At the end of the execution the cmd windows is still open and I can navigate through it.

Should I set an option in Pyinstaller? Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a input() command to end of your program to get a key before exiting.